# Pip is installed and supposed to be downloading packages, but it does not work in my coding. (Windows 10)

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

When I am installing packages using pip, it shows that everything is installed but it really isn't.

This is on Windows 10. I have tried to install other packages, the same thing happens. it's all showing as installed on command prompt, but Sublime and other code editors do not show it as installed.

`pip install pyinstaller` then it returns with: `Requirement already satisfied` and when I put it in sublime: `No module named pyinstaller`
Even when I put it in command prompt again: `pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I am expecting pip to install the package, make it work, so I can `import pyinstaller`, but it says there is no module available. What should I do?

Edit: It's not just sublime, even the cmd prompt command isnt working. pip says its installed, but cmd prompt and any external applications don't work.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong version of python in your sublime

Comment: Try `pip install pyinstaller==3.3` apparently, new versions don't seem to work

Comment: maybe the installed pyinstaller is not compatible to your python you use in sublime

Answer (score 0):

Check if `pip` version and `python` are equals. Use `pip -V` and `python -V`.

Maybe, you have multiples versions installed...

Comment: pip returns: ```pip 19.2.1 from C:\Users\PCNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)```

and python returns ```python 3.7.4```

Comment: force install with `pip3.7 install pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely due to case. Try:

```py
import PyInstaller
```

Note the capital p and I. Check in your site packages directory and see if you have a folder named PyInstaller. Also check the python scripts folder for the pyinstaller script.